# writing binary file in c++ is producing ascii output

Tags: c++, io, binaryfiles

This might be a very silly bug, but I am very confused to why my code is writing the specified data as ascii characters in the file and not in binary format? What am I missing? Most tutorials I read online followed this setup so I have to be missing something crucial. Any help is appreciated. Also the output in the file is "123456"

```
void MipsInterpret::outFile() {
std::cout << "Writing file" << std::endl;
std::ofstream myFile;
myFile.open(outputFile, std::ios::binary);
if (!myFile) {
    std::cerr << outputFile << " failed to open. Closing " << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
std::string test = "add $1, $2, $3";

char list[6] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6'};

myFile.write(list, 6);

if (!myFile.good()) {
    std::cerr << "Error occurred at writing time!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
myFile.close();
```

}

Comment: But you do have an array of six ASCII characters, so what are you expecting the file to contain (after writing those as is into it)?

Comment: I expected binary files to be unreadable so it would contain a bunch of hex values? Unless my understanding is incorrect

Comment: `'1'` character is translated to the number `0x31`, and written to file. Use `{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };` if you want the actual numbers, or use `'\x01'` to `'\xFF'`

Answer (score 1):

Insted of

```cpp
char list[6] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6'};
```

do

```cpp
char list[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

That will fix the issue because '1' is actually 49 in binary